# CMD: File tasks, open directory and select file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, explorer

I want to open a folder and automatically select a file from the command line:

```
>> explorer C:\Windows\system32\selected_file.txt
```

Once Windows Explorer has opened `C:\Windows\system32` I want `selected_file.txt` to be highlighted automatically. Is that possible with Windows Command Prompt?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
explorer.exe /select,c:\windows\system32\selected_file.txt
```

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/130510

Comment: Is there a way to select the file without opening a new window? Let's say the folder is open and I want to select a file in the open folder. How would I do that using cmd?

Comment: @akinuri: did you ever find out how to do what you have asked? What about the same for multiple files at once?

Comment: @u01jmg3 Nope. I created a [custom "New" submenu](https://superuser.com/questions/1242099/create-a-new-new-submenu-in-context-menu-with-a-custom-name) in the context menu, and wanted to be able to rename the file after its creation, you know, like the way Windows does. Kinda gave up on this "select" thing. I just do it manually.